# Why did my comments get removed?

Tags: discussion, comments

My comments below got removed half-an-hour after I wrote them. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you asked for a clarification so I edited it into the original comment. That's why the comments were removed as "obsolete."

Comment: Sounds fair, I hadn't reread your first comment.